# In angular, how do you provide a controller's argument list from within a directive definition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to follow the best practice of providing an argument list when defining a controller, like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    // stuff accomplished.
  }];
```

However, I'm not sure how to provide this argument list when the controller is embedded in a directive definition:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>{{ name }}</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        // stuff accomplished.
        $scope.name = 'Louis';
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as usual!

```
controller: ['$scope', function($scope){...}]
```